# Why stateful/stateless widgets extends and doesn't implements?

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I have this question for a job interview, and i want to know why the stateful and staless widgets, use extends and why not use implements in Flutter/Dart?

Comment: You can checkout the answer here showing difference between `extends`, `implements` and `with`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55295782/10488444

Answer (score 0):

[Extends](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class)

`extends` is usually the go-to when you want to make a more specific version of a class.

When you extend a class, you inherit all properties, methods, etc.
If you want to override a method, you prefix the method with `@override`.

[Implements](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#implicit-interfaces)

`implements` is when you want to make a whole new version of a class but you want to inherit the class type.

When you create a new implementation of a class, you are responsible for supplying everything necessary to make that class function.