# Dart implements/extends for abstract class

Tags: dart

For abstract classes is there difference between `implements` and `extends`? Which one should I use? In Java for interfaces you would use implements, but I see dart doesn't have interfaces and both implements/extends work. If I want to declare abstract class for my api methods, should I use implements or extends?

```dart
void main() {
  User user = new User();
  user.printName();
}

abstract class Profile {
  String printName();
}

class User extends Profile {
  @override
  String printName() {
    print("I work!!");
    return "Test";
  }
}
```

Comment: A complete answer is also available here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295782/extends-versus-implements-versus-with

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All classes in Dart can be used as interfaces. A class being `abstract` means you cannot make an instance of the class since some of its members might not be implemented.

`extends` means you take whatever a class already have of code and you are then building a class on top of this. So if you don't override a method, you get the method from the class you extends from. You can only extend from one class.

`implements` means you want to just take the interface of class but come with your own implementation of all members. So your class ends up being compatible with another class but does not come with any of the other class's implementation. You can implement multiple classes.

A third options, which you did not mention, is `mixin` which allow us to take the implementation of multiple `mixin` defined classes and put them into our own class. You can read more about them here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins

Comment: would it be better to write logic of methods inside an abstract class and then only extend it, or write the method name and implement somewhere else?

Comment: Depends on your application. There are also extension methods that can be useful in some scenarios: https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods . So without knowing much about your application I cannot really give any specific recommendation other than: It depends. :)

Answer (score 0):

another definition that may help you got the point.. Use extends make class inherits (extends) his parent, where you extend(have) his properties even if you don't override parent class's properties you can use the parent class's properties, methods beside his own properties and methods, also you should validate that this class(child) commits it's parent class and doesn't break the restrictions of the parent.. you can only inherit from 1 class... where as

Use implements when you want the class just restrict to the abstract class properties but you have your own implementation for these properties... use can implements multiple interfaces using "," for concatenate among the interfaces.